# BNC to 6.35mm Headphone jack wiring

Tags: wiring, kicad

Right now I am using KiCAD to try make a 6.35mm Headphone jack to BNC converter and am confused as to how to wire rn, tn and sn.

What do they do? This is my current KiCAD schematic.

[image]

Comment: do you want the mono BNC to drive both channels of your stereo jack, or do you want to combine both channels of your stereo jack to drive the mono BNC output? Hint, the latter might need a switch or resistors as well, or maybe not, depending on what you want. If you don't need insertion of the jack to break circuits (like a headphone jack could mute the speakers), then you can safely leave all the xn1 pins open circuit

Comment: This question is unanswerable until you specify what **exact** connections your application requires.  Connecting a headphone jack to an BNC jack is not a *normal* operation, so whatever clever (mis)use is being made of one of the connector types will have to come with a specification (written or discoverable) for how it is being wired to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The xN pins are switches that get activated by inserting the plug into the connector:
https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2019/may/a-deep-dive-into-audio-jack-switches-and-configurations